# PHP fopen is throwing a crazy error - refers to a different directory

Tags: php, fopen

This should be simple, but I'm blocked on figuring this out myself.

**OBJECTIVE:** Read a text file into a string to be echoed inside a `<div>`. I've done this before, but in the current program, the directory structure seems to be giving me fits.

**THE SETUP:** The main page is in a specific directory on a LINUX server, `/home4/mylogin/public_html/repository` -- let's call that CWD (current working directory).

The main page includes the file reading function from the functions.php file located at CWD/includes. This is because I want to reuse the function to read four different text files, all located in different subdirectories. (It has to do with giving others edit access to those files through FTP).

The first text file is located at `CWD/files/curator/curator.txt`

When I attempt to open the text file, using this code:

```
$handle = fopen($sourcepath,"r");
```

I get an error, no matter how I build the $sourcepath variable. Here are some variations I've tried for `$sourcepath`:

```
"/files/curator/curator.txt"
"files/curator/curator.txt" 
getcwd() . "/files/curator/curator.txt"
"http://www.websitename.com/repository/files/curator/curator.txt"
"/home4/mylogin/public_html/repository/files/curator/curator.txt"
```

and they all throw the same error when I open the page - this one:

```
fopen(/home4/dpm39110/public_html/repository/files/Curator/curator.txt):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/mylogin
/public_html/repository/includes/functions.php on line 21
```

It looks like the `fopen()` function is trying to find the txt file inside the INCLUDES directory. How can this be? Why isn't it looking in the directory I'm pointing it to?

By the way, using `chdir("/files/curator/curator.txt")` doesn't help.

I'm afraid I just need to move the file read function out of the `functions.php` file and into the main page code.

However, I'd love to understand why this is happening, and how to keep it from happening next time.

Suggestions? Thanks so much if you can help!

Comment: Make use of the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant.

Comment: checked the file\dir permissions

Comment: Leading `/` says go back to the root and start looking there

Comment: Linux servers are case-sensitive for file names.  In your example you have Curator but in other places you have curator, those are not the same.  One thing you could try is fopen("../files/curator/curator.txt").  The path would be relative to the script path so you are going up one folder and then back down into the folder with the file.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to use the `__DIR__` magic constant. It gives you the current directotry of the executing script, where it is *written*. You could use:

```
// assume the script is in /home4/mylogin/public_html/includes/
$file = __DIR__ . '/../files/curator/curator.txt';
$handle = fopen($file);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that input - I will definitely use it in the future.

However, **THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED!**

I'm embarrassed to admit how elemental the solution was. I decided to play around with the `file_exists()` function, and discovered a CAPITALIZATION issue in the file path. So Crossphire Development was right on the money.

Grrr, and forehead slap. The script is working just fine now.

Thank you all for your thoughts and inputs, and I hope I can contribute some help here for someone else soon.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.